# many a traveler

Tags: grammar

I discovered this sentence:

*Many a traveler has found the whole pub experience rather bewildering.*

The meaning is clear to me. But the phrase "Many a traveler" seems to be a bit odd to me. Can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

*Many a traveler* simply means *many travelers*. The former one is a poetic or literary way of writing it.

You may say this sentence in two ways....

> Many a time it happens that I cannot see the things that are nearer to me

**OR**

> Many times it happens that I cannot see....

Note that that typical use of singular *traveler* will take a singular verb *has*. If you change it to a normal construction, it'll take a plural verb.

> Many a traveler has found the whole pub experience rather bewildering = Many travelers have found the whole pub experience rather bewildering.